# Prove cancellation law on multiplication without using trichotomy of order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, peano-axioms

In textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by prof *D. J. H. Garling*, the author proves the cancellation law in multiplication before he moves on to prove the trichotomy of order. I have tried to prove by induction many times but to no avail. Please shed some light!

Below are properties of addition and multiplication that I can use:

> 1. Peano's axioms
> 2. Definition of Addition: Considering the (successor) mapping $s:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, setting $m_0=m$, and using recursion, there exists a sequence $(m_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $m_0=m$ and $m_{s(n)}=s(m_n)$. Define $m+n:=m_n$. Thus $m=m+0$ and $s(m)=m+1$. Hence the equation $m_{s(n)}=s(m_n)$ becomes $m+(n+1)=(m+n)+1$.
> 3. Definition of Multiplication: Suppose that $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Using recursion, there exists a sequence $(p_m)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $p_0=0$ and $p_{m+1}=p_m+n$. Define $m.n:=p_m$.
> 4. $m+n=n+m$
> 5. $(m+n)+p=m+(n+p)$
> 6. $m+n=p+n \implies m=p$
> 7. $m+n=0 \implies m=n=0$
> 8. $m.n=n.m$
> 9. $0.n=0$ and $1.n=n$
> 10. $(m.n).p=m.(n.p)$

Now I want to prove the cancellation law on multiplication:

> $m.n=p.n \wedge n \neq 0 \implies  m=p$

Here is my take:

> Let $U=\{n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \mid m.n=p.n \implies  m=p, \text{ for all } m,p \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $V=U \cup \{0\}$.
>
> It's clear that $0 \in V$.
>
> Assume $n \in V$. Then $m.n=p.n \implies  m=p$.
>
> Now we prove $n+1 \in V$ i.e. $m.(n+1)=p.(n+1) \implies  m=p$. To prove this, it is equivalent to prove $m.(n+1)=p.(n+1) \implies m.n=p.n$.

I don't know how to precede to prove $m.(n+1)=p.(n+1) \implies m.n=p.n$

PS: I updated the excerpt from textbook. As you can see, the author proves the cancellation law in multiplication (*Theorem 2.1.2*) before he proves the trichotomy of order (*Theorem 2.1.5*).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No answer from me ... but I remember trying to prove that one without trichotomy as well ... and failed. I don't know how to do this without using some sort of trichotomy at some point.

Comment: Those properties aren't sufficient because there are rings with the same properties where the cancellation law doesn't hold.

Comment: @MattSamuel: Of course, we can use Peano's axioms and the definitions of addition and multiplication as well.

Comment: @MattSamuel I have edited my post to include Peano's axioms and the definitions of addition and multiplication.

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier comment. of course you can prove the cancellation lemma using the Peano axioms ... but I don't see how you can do this without first using induction to prove some kind of theorem to the effect of $\forall x \forall y (x=y \lor \exists z (x = s(y+z)) \lor \exists z (y =s(x+z)))$ ... which is really just the trichotomy law in disguise.

Comment: @Bram28 I added images from my textbook so that you can have a full look of what the author intended to do. Please have a look at these images.

Comment: @DungLe Wow, ok, yeah, there is every suggestion by the author that a straightforward induction would suffice, but as you and I found out the hard way, that is not the case. I'd call this an oversight by the author.

Comment: There is a good proof using only the axiom in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3067506/543323

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiplication cancellation property by Peano axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875553/multiplication-cancellation-property-by-peano-axioms)